# Аргументы командной строки и пустая строка в условии

Tags: c++

Изучая c++, [наткнулся](https://ravesli.com/urok-110-argumenty-komandnoj-stroki/) на вот такой пример:

```
// В некоторых операционных системах argv[0] может быть просто пустой строкой, без имени программы
// Обрабатываем случай, когда argv[0] может быть пустым или не пустым
if (argv[0])
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <number>" << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Usage: <program name> <number>" << '\n';
```

Данный пример ввел меня в ступор. Насколько я знаю, указатель на пустую строку будет всегда `true` следовательно `else` никогда не выполнится. Либо я что-то не понимаю, либо в этом примере  ошибка и имелось ввиду не пустая строка а то, что `argv[0]` будет указывать на `nullptr`(а это, насколько я понимаю, разные понятия)

Comment: Да, указатель на пустую строку всегда не нулевой. Отличить пустую строку от непустой такой проверкой `if (argv[0])` нельзя. Единственное, элемент `argv[argc]` всегда `nullptr`. Даже если `argc` равен нулю. Т.е. ветвь `else` в принципе выполниться может. Но комментарии в тексте программы не соответствуют проверяемому условию... Что тут можно сказать... разве, что процитировать Владимира Ильича: "Не всё, что пишут в интернете, есть правда.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

стандарт :

> argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
>
> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by
> argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null
> character if the program name is not available from the host
> environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
> pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program
> parameters.

перевод :

**argv[argc]** должен быть нулевым указателем.

Если значение **argc** больше нуля, строка, на которую указывает **argv[0]**, представляет собой имя программы; **argv[0][0]** должен быть нулевым символом, если имя программы недоступно из среды хоста. Если значение **argc** больше единицы, то строки, на которые указывает от **argv[1]** до **argv[argc-1]**, представляют параметры программы.

Ваш пример неправильный. Там проверяется, что `argc == 0` и `argv[argc] == NULL`, то есть вообще нет никаких данных, ни имени программы, ни аргументов.  По стандарту сначала нужно смотреть количество строк, и потом смотреть не пустая ли строка (то есть первая буква **'\00'** , а не **NULL** указатель как в примере).

```
if ( argc and argv[0][0] )
// или, что одно и то-же так :
// if ( argv[0] and argv[0][0] )
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <number>" << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Usage: <program name> <number>" << '\n';
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот только вопрос, в каких случаях `argc` может быть меньше единицы? Ведь имя запускаемой программы у нас есть всегда, а следовательно argc будет всегда равен минимум одному. Разве нет? и следовательно в условии можно оставить только `argv[0][0]`.

Comment: имя программы может просто отсутствовать и могут отсутствовать аргументы. всё реально и может быть `argc == 0`

Comment: @VanechikSpace может быть вариант `argc==1` и пустая строка в `argv[0]`. А может быть вариант `argc==0` и тогда массив `argv` вовсе не содержит элементов. Отдельный вопрос в каких системах происходит то или иное.

Comment: На самом деле, используя вызов [execv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv), запросто можно вызвать программу, передав ей в `argv[0]` null (да, `argc` при этом будет равен 0). Так что, пример абсолютно корректный. (Кстати, передать в argv[0] можно что угодно, не обязательно имя программы)

Comment: @avp пример ТС не совсем корректный. Нужна ещё именно проверка на непустую строку. Комментарий, который добавлен к коду, ему не соответствует.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вы имеете в виду `if (argv[0] && argv[0][0]) .... `? Да, это более корректная проверка. Хотя, мне теперь кажется, что речь в комментарии в коде ТС о "системах" (скорее о загрузчиках микроконтроллеров), которые в принципе не умеют передавать аргументы